# GETDATE Function Report

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I modify this to retrieve yesterday, and 6 days ago?

Right now this returns ONLY yesterday.

```
AND (DATEDIFF(d,[dbo].[UDO_FUNC_GET_PANEL_TIME](EV2.EVENT_TIME_UTC,EV2.MACHINE),GETDATE()) = 1)
```

When I change the 1 to a 2 it returns the day before.

```
AND (DATEDIFF(d,[dbo].[UDO_FUNC_GET_PANEL_TIME](EV2.EVENT_TIME_UTC,EV2.MACHINE),GETDATE()) = 2)
```

I need it to return 7 days.

Here is the full query if needed:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UDO_VW_ExportView]
AS
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT '"'+CONVERT( NVARCHAR(20),dbo.UDO_FUNC_GET_PANEL_TIME(EV.EVENT_TIME_UTC,EV.MACHINE),101)+' '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),dbo.UDO_FUNC_GET_PANEL_TIME(EV.EVENT_TIME_UTC,EV.MACHINE),100),13,7)+'"' AS Q_EventDate_AMPM
                      ,'"'+CONVERT( NVARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),101)+' '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),100),13,7)+'"' AS Q_currentDate_AMPM
                      ,'"'+E.SSNO+'"' AS Q_CardholderId
                      ,'"'+CAST(EV.CARDNUM AS NVARCHAR(20))+'"' AS Q_BadgeId
                      ,'"'+E.LASTNAME+'"' AS Q_LastName
                      ,'"'+E.FIRSTNAME+'"' AS Q_FirstName
                      ,'"'+A.NAME+'"' AS Q_PanelName
                      ,'"'+R.READERDESC+'"' AS Q_ReaderName
FROM dbo.EMP E
     INNER JOIN dbo.EVENTS EV ON EV.EMPID = E.ID
                                 AND EV.EVENT_TIME_UTC =
(
    SELECT MIN(EV2.EVENT_TIME_UTC)
    FROM EVENTS EV2
    WHERE EV2.EMPID = E.ID
          AND EV2.EVENT_TIME_UTC > GETUTCDATE() - 3
          AND (DATEDIFF(d,[dbo].[UDO_FUNC_GET_PANEL_TIME](EV2.EVENT_TIME_UTC,EV2.MACHINE),GETDATE()) = 1)
)
     INNER JOIN dbo.ACCESSPANE A ON A.PANELID = EV.MACHINE
     INNER JOIN dbo.READER R ON R.PANELID = EV.MACHINE AND R.READERID = EV.DEVID
ORDER BY EV.EMPID, EV.EVENT_TIME_UTC
GO
```

Comment: TOP 100 PERCENT is pointless - the optimizer knows that and will ignore it.

Comment: ok, so how do i get it to show transactions 7,6,5,4,3,2 days and yesterday?

Comment: Please **DO NOT** edit your question to be meaningless once answered. Feel free to self-answer, i.e. add your answer as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `= 1` or `= 2`, use `< 7`

Comment: Yeha...Thats not working because of the MIN Statement...

Example:  MAY 17 Joe Shmoe
May 18 JOE SHMOE
May 19 JOE SHMOE

it only returns him once when it should be 3 times...for 3 different dates.

Comment: @menor59 Then add a `GROUP BY` clause if you need to see all of them. Do you have multiple entries per day? Or what is the reason you have the `MIN` clause in there?

Comment: The original intent was to run this Once a day, and get the first badge reads of the day only.  Now im trying to modify it to Retrieve All First Badge reads over a 7 day period..

Comment: @menor59 build a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle) with table structure, some sample data, and desired results. There are so many problems in your existing query it would be easier to write a better one from scratch than try to both reverse engineer it and fix it to do what you need it to do.